# rtabmap_ros tutorial zed_stereo_throttle.launch gives unused args error

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the moment I'm trying to use remote mapping on a robot with a jetson tx2 and a laptop with ubuntu 16.04.
Both run with ros kinetic.

Following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/RemoteMapping I build the throttle launch file on the jetson and recieved the following error.

```
~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch zed_wrapper zed_stereo_throttle.launch 
... logging to /home/nvidia/.ros/log/03f8b8c0-5fa8-11ea-bbd6-b0fc36b76f7b/roslaunch-tegra-ubuntu-5544.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

unused args [resolution, publish_tf, frame_rate] for include of [/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/zed-ros-wrapper/zed_wrapper/launch/zed_camera_nodelet.launch]
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I'm kinda lost here because looking at the code for the nodelet I can clearly see the args used.
Does someone have any idea as of to what I did wrong?

Thank you in advandce and for reading this.

Edit:
Thanks to matlabbes awnser I could start the launch file, but get this enourmus error message:

```
nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~$ roslaunch zed_wrapper zed_stereo_throttle.launch
... logging to /home/nvidia/.ros/log/a53abca6-638b-11ea-9403-00187daf6704/roslaunch-tegra-ubuntu-4469.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.0.15:41020/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /camera/stereo_sync/approx_sync: False
 * /camera/stereo_sync/compressed_rate: 5.0
 * /camera/zed_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /camera/zed_node/auto_exposure: True
 * /camera/zed_node/camera_model: zed
 * /camera/zed_node/confidence: 100
 * /camera/zed_node/depth/confidence_root: confidence
 * /camera/zed_node/depth/depth_stabilization: 1
 * /camera/zed_node/depth/depth_topic_root: depth
 * /camera/zed_node/depth/disparity_topic: disparity/dispari...
 * /camera/zed_node/depth/min_depth: 0.3
 * /camera/zed_node/depth/openni_depth_mode: 0
 * /camera/zed_node/depth/point_cloud_topic_root: point_cloud
 * /camera/zed_node/depth/quality: 1
 * /camera/zed_node/depth/sensing_mode: 0
 * /camera/zed_node/exposure: 100
 * /camera/zed_node/gain: 100
 * /camera/zed_node/general/base_frame: base_link
 * /camera/zed_node/general/camera_flip: False
 * /camera/zed_node/general/camera_frame: zed_camera_center
 * /camera/zed_node/general/frame_rate: 30
 * /camera/zed_node/general/gpu_id: -1
 * /camera/zed_node/general/left_camera_frame: zed_left_camera_f...
 * /camera/zed_node/general/left_camera_optical_frame: zed_left_camera_o...
 * /camera/zed_node/general/resolution: 2
 * /camera/zed_node/general/right_camera_frame: zed_right_camera_...
 * /camera/zed_node/general/right_camera_optical_frame: zed_right_camera_...
 * /camera/zed_node/general/self_calib: True
 * /camera/zed_node/general/serial_number: 0
 * /camera/zed_node/general/svo_compression: 4
 * /camera/zed_node/general/verbose: True
 * /camera/zed_node/general/zed_id: -1
 * /camera/zed_node/mapping/fused_pointcloud_freq: 1.0
 * /camera/zed_node/mapping/mapping_enabled: False
 * /camera/zed_node/mapping/resolution: 1
 * /camera/zed_node/mat_resize_factor: 1.0
 * /camera/zed_node/max_depth: 20.0
 * /camera/zed_node/point_cloud_freq: 10.0
 * /camera/zed_node/stream: 
 * /camera/zed_node/svo_file: 
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/fixed_cov_value: 1e-6
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/fixed_covariance: False
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/fixed_z_value: 1.0
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/floor_alignment: False
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/init_odom_with_first_valid_pose: True
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/initial_base_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0...
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/map_frame: map
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/odometry_db: 
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/odometry_frame: odom
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/odometry_topic: odom
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/path_max_count: -1
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/path_pub_rate: 2.0
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/pose_topic: pose
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/publish_map_tf: False
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/publish_pose_covariance: True
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/publish_tf: False
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/spatial_memory: True
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/two_d_mode: False
 * /camera/zed_node/tracking/world_frame: map
 * /camera/zed_node/video/color_enhancement: True
 * /camera/zed_node/video/left_topic_root: left
 * /camera/zed_node/video/rgb_topic_root: rgb
 * /camera/zed_node/video/right_topic_root: right
 * /camera/zed_node/video/stereo_topic_root: stereo
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.13

NODES
  /camera/
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    camera_zed_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    stereo_sync (nodelet/nodelet)
    zed_node (nodelet/nodelet)
    zed_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.10:11311

process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [4478]
process[camera/zed_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [4479]
process[camera/zed_node-3]: started with pid [4480]
[ INFO] [1583927269.994617547]: Loading nodelet /camera/zed_node of type zed_wrapper/ZEDWrapperNodelet to manager camera_nodelet_manager with the following remappings:
[ INFO] [1583927270.008940163]: waitForService: Service [/camera/camera_nodelet_manager/load_nodelet] could not connect to host [192.168.0.15:50951], waiting...
process[camera/camera_zed_link-4]: started with pid [4484]
process[camera/stereo_sync-5]: started with pid [4490]
[ INFO] [1583927270.072780419]: Loading nodelet /camera/stereo_sync of type rtabmap_ros/stereo_sync to manager camera_nodelet_manager with the following remappings:
[ INFO] [1583927270.072966604]: /camera/left/camera_info -> /camera/left/camera_info
[ INFO] [1583927270.073069585]: /camera/left/image_rect -> /camera/left/image_rect_color
[ INFO] [1583927270.073129396]: /camera/rgbd_image -> /camera/rgbd_image
[ INFO] [1583927270.073187543]: /camera/right/camera_info -> /camera/right/camera_info
[ INFO] [1583927270.073245242]: /camera/right/image_rect -> /camera/right/image_rect_color
[ INFO] [1583927270.078909785]: waitForService: Service [/camera/camera_nodelet_manager/load_nodelet] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1583927270.083429982]: Initializing nodelet with 6 worker threads.
[ INFO] [1583927270.099957058]: waitForService: Service [/camera/camera_nodelet_manager/load_nodelet] is now available.
[ INFO] [1583927270.101268933]: waitForService: Service [/camera/camera_nodelet_manager/load_nodelet] is now available.
[ INFO] [1583927270.337140841]: SDK version : 2.8.5
[ INFO] [1583927270.337243886]: *** PARAMETERS ***
[ INFO] [1583927270.339634503]:  * Camera Resolution        -> HD720
[ INFO] [1583927270.342008735]:  * Camera Framerate     -> 30
[ INFO] [1583927270.343681140]:  * Gpu ID           -> -1
[ INFO] [1583927270.345681689]:  * Camera ID            -> -1
[ INFO] [1583927270.347354702]:  * Verbose          -> ENABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.350750394]:  * Camera Flip          -> DISABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.354667584]:  * Self calibration     -> ENABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.357936133]:  * Camera Model         -> zed
[ INFO] [1583927270.384071344]:  * Depth quality        -> PERFORMANCE
[ INFO] [1583927270.385592317]:  * Depth Sensing mode       -> STANDARD
[ INFO] [1583927270.387178766]:  * OpenNI mode          -> DISABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.388541683]:  * Depth Stabilization      -> ENABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.390487637]:  * Minimum depth        -> 0.3
[ INFO] [1583927270.403877691]:  * Path rate            -> 2 Hz
[ INFO] [1583927270.405854239]:  * Path history size        -> 1
[ INFO] [1583927270.408919610]:  * Odometry DB path     -> 
[ INFO] [1583927270.412088155]:  * Spatial Memory       -> ENABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.413709005]:  * IMU Fusion           -> ENABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.416465880]:  * Floor alignment      -> DISABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.419359275]:  * Init Odometry with first valid pose data -> ENABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.422113366]:  * Two D mode           -> DISABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.426288745]:  * Publish Pose Covariance  -> ENABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.427655983]:  * Fixed covariance     -> DISABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.429029236]:  * Fixed cov. value     -> 1e-06
[ INFO] [1583927270.431934183]:  * Mapping          -> DISABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.435210509]:  * IMU timestamp sync       -> DISABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.441195484]:  * IMU data freq        -> 0 Hz
[ INFO] [1583927270.450228325]:  * SVO REC compression      -> HEVC (H265)
[ INFO] [1583927270.481608762]:  * world_frame          -> map
[ INFO] [1583927270.481682942]:  * map_frame            -> map
[ INFO] [1583927270.481729600]:  * odometry_frame       -> odom
[ INFO] [1583927270.481768930]:  * base_frame           -> base_link
[ INFO] [1583927270.481805508]:  * camera_frame         -> zed_camera_center
[ INFO] [1583927270.481838949]:  * imu_link         -> imu_link
[ INFO] [1583927270.481878599]:  * left_camera_frame        -> zed_left_camera_frame
[ INFO] [1583927270.481918025]:  * left_camera_optical_frame    -> zed_left_camera_optical_frame
[ INFO] [1583927270.481952459]:  * right_camera_frame       -> zed_right_camera_frame
[ INFO] [1583927270.481987277]:  * right_camera_optical_frame   -> zed_right_camera_optical_frame
[ INFO] [1583927270.482023311]:  * depth_frame          -> zed_left_camera_frame
[ INFO] [1583927270.482057969]:  * depth_optical_frame      -> zed_left_camera_optical_frame
[ INFO] [1583927270.482093010]:  * disparity_frame      -> zed_left_camera_frame
[ INFO] [1583927270.482126324]:  * disparity_optical_frame  -> zed_left_camera_optical_frame
[ INFO] [1583927270.482158294]:  * confidence_frame     -> zed_left_camera_frame
[ INFO] [1583927270.482192471]:  * confidence_optical_frame -> zed_left_camera_optical_frame
[ INFO] [1583927270.489497769]:  * Broadcast odometry TF    -> DISABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.492494721]:  * Broadcast map pose TF    -> DISABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.494306013]:  * [DYN] mat_resize_factor  -> 1
[ INFO] [1583927270.496319938]:  * [DYN] confidence     -> 100
[ INFO] [1583927270.498195745]:  * [DYN] max_depth      -> 20
[ INFO] [1583927270.499794290]:  * [DYN] exposure       -> 100
[ INFO] [1583927270.501177464]:  * [DYN] gain           -> 100
[ INFO] [1583927270.502553566]:  * [DYN] auto_exposure      -> ENABLED
[ INFO] [1583927270.503917539]:  * [DYN] point_cloud_freq   -> 10 Hz
[ INFO] [1583927270.529816642]:  * Camera coordinate system -> COORDINATE_SYSTEM_RIGHT_HANDED_Z_UP_X_FWD
ZED (Init) >> Depth mode: PERFORMANCE
ZED (Init) >> Video mode: HD720@30
[ INFO] [1583927272.144733544]: ZED connection -> SUCCESS
[ INFO] [1583927274.145235164]:  * CAMERA MODEL  -> ZED
[ INFO] [1583927274.145368610]:  * Serial Number -> 18463
[ INFO] [1583927274.145558539]:  * FW Version    -> 1523
[ INFO] [1583927274.300318508]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/rgb/image_rect_color
[ INFO] [1583927274.300414545]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/rgb/camera_info
[ INFO] [1583927274.333298300]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/rgb_raw/image_raw_color
[ INFO] [1583927274.333376768]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/rgb_raw/camera_info
[ INFO] [1583927274.374971286]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/left/image_rect_color
[ INFO] [1583927274.375050586]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/left/camera_info
[ INFO] [1583927274.408506050]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/left_raw/image_raw_color
[ INFO] [1583927274.408587750]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/left_raw/camera_info
[ INFO] [1583927274.446739476]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/right/image_rect_color
[ INFO] [1583927274.446925821]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/right/camera_info
[ INFO] [1583927274.484007062]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/right_raw/image_raw_color
[ INFO] [1583927274.484101723]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/right_raw/camera_info
[ INFO] [1583927274.517936277]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/depth/depth_registered
[ INFO] [1583927274.518021817]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/depth/camera_info
[ INFO] [1583927274.559468168]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/confidence/confidence_image
[ INFO] [1583927274.559560205]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/confidence/camera_info
[ INFO] [1583927274.594692230]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/stereo/image_rect_color
[ INFO] [1583927274.627668502]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/stereo_raw/image_raw_color
[ INFO] [1583927274.630222356]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/confidence/confidence_map
[ INFO] [1583927274.632762224]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/disparity/disparity_image
[ INFO] [1583927274.635572954]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/point_cloud/cloud_registered
[ INFO] [1583927274.642802364]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/pose
[ INFO] [1583927274.645218194]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/pose_with_covariance
[ INFO] [1583927274.647578662]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/odom
[ INFO] [1583927274.649778258]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/path_odom
[ INFO] [1583927274.651936124]: Advertised on topic /camera/zed_node/path_map
[ERROR] [1583927274.727104864]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/stereo_sync] of type [rtabmap_ros/stereo_sync] even after refreshing the cache: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class rtabmap_ros/stereo_sync with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  cv_camera/CvCameraNodelet image_view/disparity image_view/image libuvc_camera/driver pcl/BAGReader pcl/BoundaryEstimation pcl/ConvexHull2D pcl/CropBox pcl/EuclideanClusterExtraction pcl/ExtractIndices pcl/ExtractPolygonalPrismData pcl/FPFHEstimation pcl/FPFHEstimationOMP pcl/MomentInvariantsEstimation pcl/MovingLeastSquares pcl/NodeletDEMUX pcl/NodeletMUX pcl/NormalEstimation pcl/NormalEstimationOMP pcl/NormalEstimationTBB pcl/PCDReader pcl/PCDWriter pcl/PFHEstimation pcl/PassThrough pcl/PointCloudConcatenateDataSynchronizer pcl/PointCloudConcatenateFieldsSynchronizer pcl/PrincipalCurvaturesEstimation pcl/ProjectInliers pcl/RadiusOutlierRemoval pcl/SACSegmentation pcl/SACSegmentationFromNormals pcl/SHOTEstimation pcl/SHOTEstimationOMP pcl/SegmentDifferences pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval pcl/VFHEstimation pcl/VoxelGrid uvc_camera/CameraNodelet uvc_camera/StereoNodelet zed_wrapper/ZEDWrapperNodelet
[ERROR] [1583927274.727227430]: The error before refreshing the cache was: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class rtabmap_ros/stereo_sync with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  cv_camera/CvCameraNodelet image_view/disparity image_view/image libuvc_camera/driver pcl/BAGReader pcl/BoundaryEstimation pcl/ConvexHull2D pcl/CropBox pcl/EuclideanClusterExtraction pcl/ExtractIndices pcl/ExtractPolygonalPrismData pcl/FPFHEstimation pcl/FPFHEstimationOMP pcl/MomentInvariantsEstimation pcl/MovingLeastSquares pcl/NodeletDEMUX pcl/NodeletMUX pcl/NormalEstimation pcl/NormalEstimationOMP pcl/NormalEstimationTBB pcl/PCDReader pcl/PCDWriter pcl/PFHEstimation pcl/PassThrough pcl/PointCloudConcatenateDataSynchronizer pcl/PointCloudConcatenateFieldsSynchronizer pcl/PrincipalCurvaturesEstimation pcl/ProjectInliers pcl/RadiusOutlierRemoval pcl/SACSegmentation pcl/SACSegmentationFromNormals pcl/SHOTEstimation pcl/SHOTEstimationOMP pcl/SegmentDifferences pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval pcl/VFHEstimation pcl/VoxelGrid uvc_camera/CameraNodelet uvc_camera/StereoNodelet zed_wrapper/ZEDWrapperNodelet
[FATAL] [1583927274.727489234]: Failed to load nodelet '/camera/stereo_sync` of type `rtabmap_ros/stereo_sync` to manager `camera_nodelet_manager'
[camera/stereo_sync-5] process has died [pid 4490, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet load rtabmap_ros/stereo_sync camera_nodelet_manager left/image_rect:=left/image_rect_color right/image_rect:=right/image_rect_color left/camera_info:=left/camera_info right/camera_info:=right/camera_info rgbd_image:=rgbd_image __name:=stereo_sync __log:=/home/nvidia/.ros/log/a53abca6-638b-11ea-9403-00187daf6704/camera-stereo_sync-5.log].
log file: /home/nvidia/.ros/log/a53abca6-638b-11ea-9403-00187daf6704/camera-stereo_sync-5*.log
^C[camera/camera_zed_link-4] killing on exit
[camera/zed_node-3] killing on exit
[camera/zed_state_publisher-2] killing on exit
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1] killing on exit
[ INFO] [1583927396.919918021]: Unloading nodelet /camera/zed_node from manager camera_nodelet_manager
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346135/rtabmap_ros-tutorial-zed_stereo_throttle.launch-gives-unused-args-error/) by [Uwe](https://answers.ros.org/users/52095/uwe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems those arguments [have been removed](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper/commit/de035d32fe0e973d520209655c8ebd599e57de59#diff-7458e7258847af352889269a0111567b) from [zed_camera_nodelet.launch](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper/blob/master/zed_wrapper/launch/zed_camera_nodelet.launch). Remove those arguments from your `zed_camera_nodelet.launch`. `resolution` and `frame_rate` arguments are optional, but `publish_tf` would be modified [here](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper/blob/680c09ed494e752a528d18835431cb574a11b652/zed_wrapper/params/common.yaml#L47-L48).

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Uwe](https://answers.ros.org/users/52095/uwe/) on 2020-03-12**:
Thanks that solved the error, though I got some other issues which leaded me to reinstall rtabmap.